# Equality of Two Sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, convergence-divergence

This is part of a proof that I've been working on. Here are the assumptions:

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $\{\varphi_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is a sequence of step functions such that $\varphi_n\to f$ pointwisely on $[a,b]$ except on a set $S$. Let $$X=X\left(f<r\right)=\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)<r\}$$ and $$Y=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{i=n}^{\infty}X\left(\varphi_i<r-\frac{1}{k}\right)$$ where $$X\left(\varphi_i<r-\frac{1}{k}\right)=\left\{x\in[a,b]:\varphi_i(x)<r-\frac{1}{k}\right\}.$$ Now, I want to show that $X\smallsetminus S=Y\smallsetminus S$. I can do the $(\supseteq)$ part but not the $(\subseteq)$ part for this reason:
\begin{align*}
x\in X\smallsetminus S&\Rightarrow x\in X, x\notin S\\
&\Rightarrow f(x)<r,\ \varphi_n(x)\to f(x)
\end{align*}
If I put $\epsilon=\frac{1}{k}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then I have $|\varphi_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{1}{k}.$ However, after some manipulations, I always get $\varphi_i(x)<r+\frac{1}{k}$. Is there any other way I could get to my goal? Please share your views.

Comment: Correction: It's $X\smallsetminus S=Y\smallsetminus S$ that I want to show.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, if $x\in X\setminus S$, then $f(x)<r$, and $\langle\varphi_n(x):n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\to f(x)$. Since $f(x)<r$, there is a $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $f(x)<r-\frac1k$. Now let $\epsilon=\left(r-\frac1k\right)-f(x)>0$; there is an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $|\varphi_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m$, and hence $\varphi_n(x)<r-\frac1k$ whenever $n\ge m$.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your answer. May I ask what result guarantees the existence of $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f(x)<r-\frac{1}{k}$ whenever $f(x)<r$?

Comment: Is it due to the density of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @mathnoob: The sequence $\left\langle r-\frac1k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$ converges to $r$, so if $f(x)<r$, then $f(x)<r-\frac1k$ for all sufficiently large $k$: you just need $k$ big enough so that $\frac1k<r-f(x)$.

Comment: Sir, is this argument also valid?
\begin{align*}
f(x)<r&\Rightarrow r-f(x)>0\\
&\Rightarrow\text{ there exists }k\in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that }\frac{1}{k}<r-f(x)\text{ (according to the Archimedean Principle)}
\end{align*}

Comment: @mathnoob: Yes, that's really the argument that I was using; I just didn't make an explicit appeal to the Archimedean principle.

Comment: @mathnoob: You're very welcome.